# Слово с нулевым корнем?

Tags: корень-слова

Есть ли в русском языке слово с нулевым корнем?

Answer (score 0):

**[Слова без корня в русском языке](https://pikabu.ru/story/slova_bez_kornya_v_russkom_yazyike_5059401)**

> В русском языке, как ни странно, существуют слова без корня. Это
> глаголы ***снять, поднять, принять, занять, вынуть, взять, изъять*** и
> т. д. Они образованы таким способом: приставка, суффикс -н
> (встречается не во всех), глагольный суффикс и окончание. Ко всем этим
> глаголам можно подобрать пару несовершенного вида, которая будет
> содержать в себе морфему "-им-": поднимать, принимать и т. д. Как ни
> странно, это корень этих слов. Все они образованы от слова "иметь". То
> есть, хотя эти слова между собой имеют мало общего, они образованы от
> одного и того же слова. Также от этих слов образуются существительные
> или прилагательные, имеющие в своём составе морфему "-ём-" или "-йм-":
> приём, займ, выемный. Это тот же корень, но здесь происходит
> чередование.

---

Грамота.ру

[Вопросы](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F) 277818, 255519, 239497,  212104, 210775

> *Вынуть* – единственное в русском языке слово без корня. Когда-то в этом слове корень был, но утратился вследствие исторических
> преобразований. Слово появилось по аналогии с глаголами на *-нуть*
> (типа двинуть) на базе *вынять*, производного от *яти*  'брать' (от
> него же образован и глагол *взять*).